# Somone 'has been friends' with someone -what is this structure?

Tags: idioms

From some Indian Daily -

> Sania has been friends with Tia since childhood.

Why plural *friends?* and why *with*? We can be *friendly* with someone, not *friend.*

Based on that, is this correct?

> Jack is friend *with* me?

Also, plural *friends* should be this way -

> Sania and Tia have been *friends* since their childhood **or** 
>   Sania has been a friend *of* Tia since childhood.

Comment: @StoneyB Oh I see. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

It's an idiom. "Be/make friends ( with somebody) that means "to be/ become a friend of somebody". E.g.,  I've been friends with George for ages. And instead of "Jack is friends with me" I would say "Jack and I are friends" or  "Jack is a friend of mine".